# Making a variable to be used inside a class functions

Tags: php, class

I have read all topics related to this issue, but none of them worked for me.

I am including a class file and before including that I defined a gameid that should be used in class file

```
here is my code :

$game_id = (int) $_GET['g']; // get id
define("_GAMEID",$game_id);

function show_game(){
        global $game_id;
        include("includes/class.files.php");
                new game_class();

}

// class.files.php
class game_class{

    public function getContent() {
        global $game_id;
        die($game_id);
        // die(_GAMEID);
    //die($GLOBALS['game_name']);
    //die($this->game_id);

        }


}
```

Really funny none of these works for me to get the current id of the game;

Comment: $_GET is already global.

Comment: and so what?  why dose it return 0 when running the class.

Comment: Dont be so upset:) you are really getting get, i mean before your vodooo?

Answer (score 0):

when you first defined:

```
global $game_id;  //include this too!!
$game_id = (int) $_GET['g']; // get id
```

Comment: even though I global it in the function but your way was not working either. It returns 0 .

Comment: @MacTaylor `$_GET['g']` must be zero or NaN in that case, you can check whats your `print_r($_GET);`  and showing zero seems to be working according to me, since the integer convert is happening here.

Comment: Why not store it into session??

Comment: @Bert then add extra management to removing those session data correctly?

Comment: @linuxeasy absolutely.. i think what he's up to is the usability of the variable to be global for classes. But session is also sa safe way if for me. but your free to use want you want.

Comment: Thanks Bert, session is a good way , I like it , but I really want to know what the hell is wrong with using this global inside class functions